# Big discrepancy in ruby Time arithmetic used with active support Time extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, date-arithmetic, activesupport

This code should not have, to my understanding, produce different results between third and second examples.

```
0> Time.utc(1999, 12, 29) - Time.utc(1999, 12, 29)
=> 0.0

0> Time.utc(1999, 12, 29) + 1.month - Time.utc(1999, 12, 29)
=> 2678400.0

0> 1.month.to_i
=> 2592000
```

Oddly enough when I convert everything to Fixnum it's back to working as expected.

```
0> Time.utc(1999, 12, 29).to_i + 1.month.to_i - Time.utc(1999, 12, 29).to_i
=> 2592000
```

What is going on?

Comment: I think I'm getting it, but can't find proof.. "+ 1.month" adapts to the month it is being appended to ? and the result my last examples works as expected (the to_i) is because there month doesn't have context, so it uses current month.

Answer (score 0):

`Time` + `1.month` usually returns same day of the next month (can be +31 days), but `1.month.to_i` equals 30 days

```
irb> Time.utc(1999, 12, 29) + 1.month
 => 2000-01-29 00:00:00 UTC
irb> Time.utc(1999, 12, 29) + 1.month.to_i
 => 2000-01-28 00:00:00 UTC
```

(In your example the difference is `86400` seconds which equals 1 day)